# Why my Java Simple Elasticsearch stuck on doSample method?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, error-handling, client, host

I have my very simple java application and I want to try indexing to the elasticsearch server that separated from my computer. So I, decided to use TransportClient object for my client like this :

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("elastichost"), 9300));
```

But, when I debugged the proccess, I got stuck on "addTransportAddress" method there with no error message. And when I tried to debug deeper, I got my apps stuck on doSample() on TransportClientNodesService.class. The process on my browser just run and run, without stop and display error message. So do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked that your computer can resolve the name `elastichost`?
You can check via `ping elastichost`

Looks like your system cannot resolve the name

Comment: I've check that my computer can resolve that host with ping, but I don't know why I got this error. By the way, do you have a simple elasticsearch application? Thanks

Comment: No I have not, but I looked to the source and that method tries to find a node to join. My main guess stands, I think there is some misconfiguration on network level or the node is not started when you tried.

Comment: I want to ask again, is there any configuration I need to do? I just download the elasticsearch, extract it, run the service and it receive rest service in the web browser. But, if I want to use JAVA API, is there any configuration I need to do? Thanks...